# How to avoid repeating "from . import class_name" when "." is actually referring to an invalid identifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

Say I have the very simple folder architecture below when working with a PyCharm project:

```
- 1 - Something
   - scripta.py
   - scriptb.py
   - dummyclass.py
```

Since `1 - Something` is an invalid identifier I have to use something like below in `scripta.py` and `scriptb.py` in order to be able to import DummyClass defined in `dummyclass.py`:

```
from .dummyclass import DummyClass
```

Is there any way to avoid that since both scripts and the class definition are within the same package without changing this invalid identifier?

I thought creating an `__init__.py` and putting the `import` there would help but it actually does not...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just rename the folder?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, cannot really do that, let's just say that I'm heavily depending on someone else's code base...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the directory can't be renamed - if it's someone else's codebase it's just as invalid for them as it is for you. But assuming you can't, one solution is to put that directory directly on the Python path; either from outside Python by adding it to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or from inside by adding it to `sys.path`. After that you can just import the module directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it sounds weird but if I ended up posting that question  it's because I don't really have the "authority" (neither the negotiation skills good enough) to do whatever I need (for instance, changing the name of the directory).